# while loop in my program does not fill the second row

Tags: matlab, while-loop

I have 2 inner `while` loops. Code writes the results to first row on the matrix but when it gets to second row, it just passes the other rows and doesn't fill the columns of the rows. How to solve it? The code and output are like below:

```
while i <= m-1
    i
    while a <= m-1
        a
        den1 = sqrt(((xy{i,j}-xy{a+1,b})^2+(xy{i,j+1}-xy{a+1,b+1})^2 ));
        dMat(i,a) = den1;
        a = a+1;
    end
    i = i+1;
end
```

```
i = 1

a = 1 
a = 2 
a = 3 
a = 4
a = 5
a = 6 
a = 7 
a = 8 
a = 9 
a = 10 
a = 11 
a = 12 
a = 13 
a = 14 
a = 15 
a = 16 
a = 17 
a = 18 
a = 19 
a = 20 
a = 21 
a = 22 
a = 23 
a = 24

i = 2
i = 3
i = 4
i = 5
i = 6
i = 7
i = 8
i = 9
i = 10
i = 11
i = 12
i = 13
i = 14
i = 15
i = 16
i = 17
i = 18
i = 19
i = 20
i = 21
i = 22
i = 23
i = 24
```

Comment: This is where `for` is much more useful than `while`.

Answer (score 5):

You have to restart `a` to `a=1` for each iteration. Put it above the `while a <= m-1`